# WiX setup: adding a reference to Visual Studio project output issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.6

I'm trying to learn WiX and now creating sample setup project, using WiX Setup Project template for Visual Studio.

I have a solution with three projects:

- .net class library;
- .net application, which uses class library;
- WiX setup project.

Of course, I want to add my first two projects' output as components to WiX setup.

As described [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_votive_project.htm) and [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/components-of-a-different-color) (and as far, as I understand), adding a reference in WiX project and setting it `Harvest` property to `True` automatically adds a component for project's output.

Now, I want to reference to this component in some `Feature` description.

The questions:

- what `Id` for `ComponentRef` should I use?
- is this the correct way to reference VS projects' output?

I'm using VS 2010 and WiX 3.6 RC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently Harvesting referenced project outputs does not work in Wix3.6 and will be [added in Wix4.0](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/2639)

For now you will have to manually add the binary outputs into your project yourself (which I personally prefer anyway). For the examples below the Components will be named the same as their Child File elements (dotNetClass.Output and dotNetApp.Output).

```
<Component>
    <File Id="dotNetClass.Output"
          Name="$(var.dotNetClass.TargetFileName)"
          Source="$(var.dotNetClass.TargetPath)"
          KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>

<Component>
    <File Id="dotNetApp.Output"
          Name="$(var.dotNetApp.TargetFileName)"
          Source="$(var.dotNetApp.TargetPath)"
          KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been added components manually... but then I've decided, that some automation in this process will be nice.

Comment: FYI it's $(var.VisualStudioProjectName.MacroName).  A project may have 0, 1 or many classes.

Comment: how i can add 2 folders in directory to out put ? @caveman_dick

Comment: @SOFKiNG I don't get what you mean. If the above question doesn't answer what you need you should ask a separate question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use [HarvestProject](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestprojects.html), [HeatDirectory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html) and [HarvestDirectory](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html) MsBuild tasks:

These are needed to embedded into your *.wixproj file or you can create a separate MSBuild compatible proj file.